# How to create a Time Plot across multiple variables in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

How am I able to create a time plot out of this dataset? This is what I have so far in R:

```
ggplot(gene_time, aes(x=Gene_Sample, y=time(c(time1,time2, time3, time4, time5, time6)), color=))+geom_line(lwd=2)+geom_hline(yintercept = 0, lwd =0.5, color='black', )theme_classic()+theme(axis.title=element_text(size=20, face= 'bold'),axis.text = element_text(size = 14, color = 'black')
```

the error I get:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (19): y

```
Gene_Sample    time1       time2          time3       time4      time5       time6
  gene_1    14.55153219   7.15685       41.433718   64.178973   80.89528    127.10444
  gene_2    7.06247951   15.192533      33.80188     55.4054    86.15328    110.73804
  gene_3   -18.41869752   4.806256      13.799425   69.307758   61.74546    98.10358
  gene_4    13.83952486   14.386315     42.029759   42.930306   114.87758   95.95243
  gene_5    1.56236267    29.595991     33.938793   35.562725   68.20763    96.326
  gene_6    -0.83575228   34.048379     38.374029   46.255315   90.50204    128.95565
  gene_7    24.15331104   34.529828     27.133572   68.515905   81.6487     102.2165
  gene_8    0.47936124    18.484483     48.435873   51.907684   51.50165    125.01297
  gene_9    17.96563166   18.020625     27.264127   46.09835    73.8649     90.26594
  gene_10   3.43030604    22.766157     48.297911   42.148587   73.83335    116.82253
  gene_11   -18.15810768  28.954761     64.717171   67.404333   92.81135    86.49371
  gene_12   8.64293762    34.168422     23.97448    71.256738   60.47921    104.24345
  gene_13   -6.88825729   24.523554     45.946685   65.569029   80.86615    87.90427
  gene_14   20.79652982   27.214529      8.821715   61.251599   72.30392    90.13581
  gene_15   16.4500108    -1.664044     29.606843   18.104112   68.17864    106.25611
  gene_16   23.84573933   10.168755     47.334708   51.5396     101.20523   126.96802
  gene_17   7.43339086     3.492704     27.625809   71.749935   76.6037     123.44657
  gene_18   17.44227553    1.617175     38.947169   80.17032    91.51059    85.9261
  gene_19   5.51995322    13.616617     12.930882   64.318664   104.28598   101.81602
```

[image]

Comment: `y=time(c(time1,time2, time3, time4, time5, time6))` and `color=` don't mean anything. What are you attempting?

Comment: I am trying to call each column for some reason it does not work, I am trying to create a ggplot for gene expression times